# Code works in Chrome but infinite loop in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code to dynamically change the text of a span element. It works in chrome, only changing the content of the span once, but does an infinite loop in IE (the count keeps updating and the html text keeps changing). Anyone know how I can fix it or why its happening?

```
bindFlagUpdate();
function bindFlagUpdate(){
    $(document).bind('flagGlobalAfterLinkUpdate', function(event, data) {
        var string = $('#like-' + data.contentId).html();
        var getNum = string.match(/[0-9]+/g);           
        var count = getNum[0];

        if(data.flagStatus == 'flagged') {
            count++;            
        } else {
            count--;        
        }           
        $('#like-' + data.contentId).html("1 user likes this");

        $(document).unbind();
        bindFlagUpdate();
        return false;
    });
}
```

Description of the event:

> The flagGlobalAfterLinkUpdate event This event is triggered
>   immediately after a flag link has been updated. (Flag links appear in
>   two flavors: "Bookmark this!" and "Unbookmark this!", and when we
>   speak of "update" we mean this change in appearance).

The even is attached to a "flag" button

Comment: 1st of all, I think `string` is a reserved word, and shouldn't be used. Second of all, have you tried debugging with console.log?

Comment: bindFlagUpdate calls bindFlagUpdate, you bind this anonymous function to the event an infinite number of times!

Comment: I have no idea what console.log is. I'm new, sorry. But im looking into it

Comment: why do you need to unbind the event right inside the bind?
`$(document).unbind();`

Answer (score 2):

To answer this we need to know more about the event `flagGlobalAfterLinkUpdate` and how it is triggered. It sounds like something in the callback function for the event is triggering the event, so once it's triggered once, it triggers itself continuously.

Comment: Possibly differences between what triggers the event. Could the line:

$('#like-' + data.contentId).html("1 user likes this");

Possibly trigger it?

Comment: It should only trigger when someone clicks the "flag this" button